# How to access a global scope object inside an Angular function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In the following controller, I have defined `$scope.dataSourceFactory`.  I initially had `var dataSourceFactory = ...`, (not using `$scope` in defining or using it later in `defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor()` but same issue).

```
app.controller('projectEditorController', ['$scope', '$log', 'dataSourceFactory',
    // the abstract data factory accepts controller type parameters for RESTful CRUD

    function ($scope, $log, dataSourceFactory) {

        $scope.dataSourceFactory = new dataSourceFactory("/odata/ProjectEditor");

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: $scope.dataSourceFactory.projects(),
            pageable: true,
            height: 400,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                        { field: "...", editable: true, width: 190, title: "Name", validation: { required: { message: "Name is required" } } },
                        { field: "DefaultContentType", title: "Default Content Type", width: "160px", editor: defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#=ContentTypes.Descriptions#" },
                        { command: ["edit", "destroy"] }
            ],
            editable: "inline"
        });

        function defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
            var dataSourceFactory = new $scope.dataSourceFactory("/odata/ContentType"); // error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
            var dsContentTypes = dataSourceFactory.contentTypes();  // returns a kendo.data.DataSource() object

            $('<input required data-text-field="Description" data-value-field="ContentTypeId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataSource: dataSourceFactory.contentTypes()
                }); // kendoDropDownList
        }


    }]);
```

Upon calling the edit/create function, the  `defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor()` function is called, which needs to make use of the `$scope.dataSourceFactory`.  The problem is, as in the comments, I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

I'm pretty sure this is a scoping issue, but not sure how to resolve.

Suggestions?

**-- UPDATE --**

As requested, here's an the factory:

```
app.factory('dataSourceFactory', function (abstractDataFactory, customFunctions) {
    var dataFactory;

    function dataSourceFactory(odataUrlBase) {
        dataFactory = new abstractDataFactory(odataUrlBase);
    }

    dataSourceFactory.prototype = {
        contentTypes: function () {
            return new kendo.data.DataSource({
            ...

return dataSourceFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error line should read:

```
        var dataSourceFactory = new dataSourceFactory("/odata/ContentType");
```

unless your `new dataSourceFactory("/odata/ProjectEditor")` returns a function/object prototype?

Alternatively it would be helpful to see your factory code too

**EDIT :**

To me the error reads that whatever is returned from the line

```
$scope.dataSourceFactory = new dataSourceFactory("/odata/ProjectEditor");
```

isn't an object prototype which can be instanciated but rather a `new kendo.data.DataSource({});` on which you can call say a `fetch` command.

I have to agree with koolunix above that you are'nt doing this in a very "Angular" way.
I'm not very familiar with Kendo but I have looked into using the [Angular-Kendo](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/) project which you may consider as an alternative to the JQuery manipulation you are doing in you controller

Edit 2:

Also for clarification this is certainly not a scope error but just to be sure you can write your function as:

```
    $scope.defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor = function(container, options) {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Updated question with that.  I initially tried using `var`, but same issue.  Also put in the data factory code for ref.

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive rather than the jquery selector '#grid', controller isn't meant for all this DOM manipulation:

```
.directive('mygrid',function(dataSourceFactory) {
    return {
        link : function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
            $element.kendoGrid({
            dataSource: $scope.dataSourceFactory.projects(),
            pageable: true,
            height: 400,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                        { field: "...", editable: true, width: 190, title: "Name", validation: { required: { message: "Name is required" } } },
                        { field: "DefaultContentType", title: "Default Content Type", width: "160px", editor: defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#=ContentTypes.Descriptions#" },
                        { command: ["edit", "destroy"] }
            ],
            editable: "inline"
        });

        function defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
            var dataSourceFactory = dataSourceFactory("/odata/ContentType");
            var dsContentTypes = dataSourceFactory.contentTypes();  // returns a kendo.data.DataSource() object

            $('<input required data-text-field="Description" data-value-field="ContentTypeId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataSource: dataSourceFactory.contentTypes()
                }); // kendoDropDownList
        }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I moved this into a directive, but still experiencing the same issue, where I can't access the injected `dataSourceFactory` from inside the `defaultCOntentTypeDropDownEditor()` function.  I removed the directive and now defining the grid within right on the view code, but experiencing problems. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363308/how-to-define-a-row-template-with-angular-kendo-within-a-grid-control